# Failed to read marionette port with EC2 Ubuntu, Python, Selenium, Geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, geckodriver

OS : AWS EC2 Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 
Python : 3.10.6 
Firefox : Mozilla Firefox 107.0 
Geckodriver : 0.32.0 (2022-11-10) 
UFW(Ubuntu Firewall) : Inactive 
Others : latest version

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOption
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

options = FirefoxOption()
options.headless = True

service = FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install())
# <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f008f2a7c70>

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    service=service,
    options=options
)
```

When I ran this code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/tool-lKp4P5xD/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 197, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options, keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/tool-lKp4P5xD/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 290, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/tool-lKp4P5xD/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 383, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/tool-lKp4P5xD/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 450, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/tool-lKp4P5xD/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Failed to read marionette port
```

I got the problem.

In my opinion, I think it is a communication problem between Geckodriver and Firefox.
But I don't know how to fix it.

Additionally, I already tried using 'pyvirtualdisplay' or 'xvfb'. 
But the result is same.
(https://azevedorafaela.com/tag/headless-browser-in-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2):

I found another way.

I read this post.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10813

I think it is a problem when you install Firefox on Ubuntu Snap package manager.

It works on Ubuntu 20.04.
Because Snap is not default package manager on that version.

It could be another solution to remove Snap on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

I think there is bug in firefox binary installed using apt/snap, I faced same issue when I installed firefox from apt package respository. I solved this by downloading firefox from [official mozilla source](https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/116.0.3/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-116.0.3.tar.bz2) and symlinked binary to /usr/bin/firefox/

First remove firefox from you system.

```
apt remove firefox
```

Download firefox from official source. (You may need to replace download URL)

```
wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/116.0.3/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-116.0.3.tar.bz2
```

Extract downloaded archive to location you want. I am using opt to extract archive.

```
tar -xf firefox-116.0.3.tar.bz2 --directory /opt/
```

Then symlink firefox binary to /usr/bin

```
ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove one version of `geckodriver` installed, since I had two of them:

Check with `whereis geckodriver`. In my case, that result was:

`geckodriver: /usr/bin/geckodriver /snap/bin/geckodriver`

I removed one version with `sudo rm /usr/bin/geckodriver` and the error that you've described (`selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Failed to read marionette port`) didn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying all the suggestions presented and was stuck as well.

```
 OS : AWS EC2 Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
 Python : 3.14
 Selenium: 4.16.0
 Firefox : Mozilla Firefox 120.0
 Geckodriver : 0.33.0
```

I firmly believe I was running into a resource issue on the EC2 instance.  I was using a t2.micro instance that would hang for 60 seconds until the error "Failed to reach Marionnette port.".  From the log file I could see that an internal python component was stuck trying to reach the "localhost:marrionetteport" .

Definitely follow the install instructions to ensure both firefox and geckodriver are on "the path".  I followed the instructions to install firefox from apt not snap.  Test if geckodriver and firefox respond to their respective start commands from the prompt.

```
>>>geckodriver 
1704305882023   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
>>>firefox
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
```

Then you know that they are on the path at least.

Add this to your python module to give you some more insight to your actual issue.

```
#import logging
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

What seemed to work for me was stopping the EC2 instance, wait until stopped, and then change the instance type by selecting the instance, clicking actions ->instance settings->Change Instance Type. Select t2.medium.  Then start the instance.

I also went so far as to define the path and port using the new service module.

Here is my working code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")

        options.set_preference('devtools.jsonview.enabled',False)
        service = Service(
            executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver',
            service_log_path="./logs/geck_log.log",
            port=58631
        )
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,service=service)
```